# Sequelize + Postgres intermittent errors

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a Node/Express/Sequelize app that connects to a Postgres database when you start it up. I force sync on startup and I get intermittent errors. The cycle goes like this:

- First start: Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: could not open relation with oid 34123
- Second start: Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: relation "boxAttributeNames" does not exist
- Third start: No errors.

And it just keeps repeating this sequence of errors. I've tried rebuilding the indexes, deleting all the tables in the database but no luck. Thankfully this project is in its infancy and I could easily drop the database and rebuild if necessary but if it's not a corruption issue, I'd like to get it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

As I was writing this, it occurred to me that I was messing with the sync'ing functionality prior to these problems starting. I was trying to force a column's constraints to be updated.

So in my frenzy, I had something like this going on:

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize('myconnectionstring', 
  { 
    sync: { 
      force: true
    }
  });

sequelize.sync({ force: true });
```

The dual sync'ing calls were creating these rolling errors.